# Unzipping number of files iteratively by using Python

Tags: python, operating-system, iteration

I have 2 TBs of data, and I have to unzip the files to do some analysis. However, due to hard disc space problem, I can not unzip all of the files at once. What I thought is unzipping first two thousand of them first, then doing my analysis and repeating it for the next 2000. How I could do it ?

```
import os, glob
import zipfile


root = 'C:\\Users\\X\\*'
directory = 'C:\\Users\\X'
extension = ".zip"
to_save = 'C:\\Users\\X\\to_save'

#x = os.listdir(path)[:2000]
for folder in glob.glob(root):
    if folder.endswith(extension): # check for ".zip" extension
        try:
            print(folder)
            os.chdir(to_save)
            zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(directory, folder)).extractall(os.path.join(directory, os.path.splitext(folder)[0]))

        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Do you really think it is a duplicate ?

Comment: What I need to do is get the first 2000, so files listed inbetween 1-2000; then 2001- 4000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about?:

```
import os
import glob
import zipfile

root = 'C:\\Users\\X\\*'
directory = 'C:\\Users\\X'
extension = ".zip"
to_save = 'C:\\Users\\X\\to_save'

# list comp of all '.zip' folders
folders = [folder for folder in glob.glob(root) if folder.endswith(extension)]

# only executes while there are folders remaining to be processed
while folders:
    # only grabs the next 2000 folders if there are at least that many
    if len(folders) >= 2000:
        temp = folders[:2000]
    # otherwise gets all the remaining (i.e. 1152 were left)
    else:
        temp = folders[:]

    # list comp that rebuilds with elements not pulled into 'temp'
    folders = [folder for folder in folders if folder not in temp]

    # this was all your code, I just swapped 'x' in place of 'folder'
    for x in temp:
        try:
            print(x)
            os.chdir(to_save)
            zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(directory, x)).extractall(os.path.join(directory, os.path.splitext(x)[0]))
        except:
            pass
```

This makes a temporary list of the .zip's and then removes those elements from the original list. Only drawback is that `folders` gets modified so eventually it will be empty if you ever needed to use it elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I found different solution, saved file paths to csv rather than saving them to a list